# problem with the error function (erf(x)) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run this code in Matlab :

```
x = [0:0.5:2];

fonc_erreur = erf(x);

plot(x,fonc_erreur, 'r');
title('Fonction erf(x) et son développement de Taylor de degré 7');
xlabel('Interval de x');
```

However, when I do, I have this error with the fonc_erreur line : Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Most of the research I did told me that most of the time it's because there's another variable named erf that is causing the problem, but in my case The code here is the only one that I have.

What can I do to solve it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Type `clear` before running your code.

Comment: Thank you it worked!

Comment: That means that you did have a variable called `erf` in your workspace. When you run a script, it knows about all the variables that are already defined before you start the script. To avoid this, write functions, not scripts.

Comment: oh ok thank you for the information